# Re-populate struts2 checkboxlist data from database

Tags: jquery, struts2, checkboxlist

I've a checkbox like

`<s:checkbox name="modProcessVO.byWeeklyCal" id="week">Days of the Week</s:checkbox>`

and another checkboxlist `

```
<s:checkboxlist list="{'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'}"   name="modProcessVO.weeklyCal" id="days" />`.
```

When I check the checkbox it's value will store as 'true' otherwise 'false' in database. If it is 'true' then only I'm saving the checked list of data from the checkboxlist. So when I want to modify the data I need to re-populate it back from DB to checkboxlist as checks . I tried by taking the days from db in action in a list of string called 'wordList' and written in jsp like

```
`<s:checkboxlist list="{'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'}" 
name="modProcessVO.weeklyCal" value="%{wordList}" id="days" />`.
```

But say if 5 values are in that list only 1st one is repopulating to checkboxlist. Pls help.
Thanks

Comment: Need a little help on this guys..pls give any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

does the wordList type is Strin[] ?

```
private String[] wordList ;
```

### **Updated answer**

```
private String[] checkedItems;
checkedItems = new String[]{"Mon","Tue","Wed"};
```

In jsp page

```
<s:checkboxlist list="checkboxListIs" name="checkedItem" value="checkedItems" label="Days"></s:checkboxlist>
```

the list,name and value are different variables in my action class.

Comment: private String checkListData;

private List<String> wordList;
      



         public String modifySchedule() {


checkListData = modProcessVO.getCalWeek();

  String regex=",";

  String[] test=checkListData.split(regex);

  wordList = Arrays.asList(test);
}

Comment: I'm getting the days I saved to db as String initially. So for passing it to jsp page, 1st converted to String[] type and then to List<String>. Then giving in jsp page as <s:checkboxlist list="{'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'}" 
name="modProcessVO.weeklyCal" value="%{wordList}" id="days" />

Comment: Hello  DayanandaEswar, I tried the way you suggested. But still it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

In action class

```
public class ScheduleAction extends ActionSupport {
```

`private String checkListData;`

```
private List<String> wordList;

public String modifySchedule() {
checkListData = modProcessVO.getCalWeek(); // retrieving checked items from database
    String regex=",";
    String[] test=checkListData.split(regex);
    wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String str : test)
    {
        wordList.add(str.trim());
    }
return SUCCESS;
}
//getters and setters of variables

}
```

In jsp I'm giving like

`<s:checkboxlist list="{'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'}"
            name="modProcessVO.weeklyCal" id="days" value="wordList"/>`